# optimum time to ask a question to maximise its probabililty of response

Tags: discussion, statistics

I regularly look at two stackexchange sites, mathematics and physics, and have noticed that there seem to be a lot more questions about mathematics than physics over a given time period. Given this, any question asked in mathematics is likely to soon be swamped by newer questions and has a greater chance of not being viewed. What is the optimum time to ask a mathematics question to maximise its probability of being viewed and answered with the constraint that the question is being asked in the UK and (presumably) the majority of users are from the USA?

Comment: If you can apply math to solve  this question then maybe...this question is suitable here @jim

Comment: Are you aware that StackExcahnge has published all its posts here: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange....might be a good place to start.

Comment: Also note that it is not always true that $P(Viewed) = P(Aswered)$...for example, I frequently jump to my "filters" view, since I know nothing about "topology", "abstract algebra" or many, many other topics asked about here...I'm moderately conversant in stats and probability, so I purposely limit myself to those questions.

Comment: Note also, that if you ask a question when almost no other comes, might be because most of the people sleep and thus, will not see your question anyway.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a certain time of day where the rate of new questions is lowest, so your question will remain on the front page longer?  But won't that also be the time of day when fewer people come here and have a chance to see your question on the front page?